# deleting the parent of a parent that was appended to element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a button that will delete a div and it's contents after it has been appended to it's parent element. I've got some working code to add a group of elements, but I've become stuck on how to remove a group once it's been added. Here's what I've got so far:

```js
function createFrag(htmlStr) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    while (temp.firstChild) {
        frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
    }
    return frag;
}

function addInputs (){

    var fragment = createFrag('<div class="input-container"><div><input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" placeholder="input 1"><input type="number" id="input2" name="input2" placeholder="input 2"></div><div><button type="button" class="btn add" onclick="return addInputs()">Add Input</button><button type="button" class="btn del" onclick ="deleteInputs()">Delete Input</button></div></div>');
    
    var div = document.createElement("div")
    div.classList.add("input-container")
    div.appendChild(fragment)
    document.getElementById('grandparent').appendChild(div);
}

function deleteInputs (event){
  var target = this.parentNode.parentNode
  document.removeChild(target)
}
```

```html
<div id="grandparent">
  <div class="input-container">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" placeholder="input 1">
        <input type="number" id="input2" name="input2" placeholder="input 2">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn add" onclick="return addInputs()">Add Input</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn del" onclick ="deleteInputs()">Delete Input</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know that the last function doesn't work, but I think it's close to what I need. What would I do to remove the same group of elements that I just added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you do not want to delete the first group of inputs. So remove the delete button from first pair of inputs. You can pass `this` to the function then try:

```
element.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
```

```js
document.querySelector('.input-container > div > .del').remove();

function createFrag(htmlStr) {
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
      temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
  while (temp.firstChild) {
      frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
  }
  return frag;
}

function addInputs (){
  var fragment = createFrag('<div class="input-container"><div><input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" placeholder="input 1"><input type="number" id="input2" name="input2" placeholder="input 2"></div><div><button type="button" class="btn add" onclick="return addInputs()">Add Input</button><button type="button" class="btn del" onclick ="deleteInputs(this)">Delete Input</button></div></div>');

  var div = document.createElement("div")
  div.classList.add("input-container")
  div.appendChild(fragment);
  document.getElementById('grandparent').appendChild(div);
}

function deleteInputs (element){
  element.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="grandparent">
  <div class="input-container">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" placeholder="input 1">
        <input type="number" id="input2" name="input2" placeholder="input 2">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn add" onclick="return addInputs()">Add Input</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn del" onclick ="deleteInputs()">Delete Input</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Clicking the first delete button doesn't work.. should be easy fix though.

Comment: Thanks! This is very close to the functionality that I'm imagining. I'll probably make the delete button on the first input group disabled if the number of groups is < 2.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `this` in the delete inputs function and remove it from there.

```js
function createFrag(htmlStr) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    while (temp.firstChild) {
        frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
    }
    return frag;
}

function addInputs (){

    var fragment = createFrag('<div class="input-container"><div><input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" placeholder="input 1"><input type="number" id="input2" name="input2" placeholder="input 2"></div><div><button type="button" class="btn add" onclick="return addInputs()">Add Input</button><button type="button" class="btn del" onclick ="deleteInputs(this)">Delete Input</button></div></div>');
    
    var div = document.createElement("div")
    div.classList.add("input-container")
    div.appendChild(fragment)
    document.getElementById('grandparent').appendChild(div);
}

function deleteInputs (input){
  input.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="grandparent">
  <div class="input-container">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" placeholder="input 1">
        <input type="number" id="input2" name="input2" placeholder="input 2">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn add" onclick="return addInputs()">Add Input</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn del" onclick ="deleteInputs(this)">Delete Input</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a fragment you can clone the div.The only issue(if it is issue) is that if some input is provided and then cloned the cloned div will have the same input.

To delete the current element you can use `remove()`

```js
function addInputs(e) {
  var fragment = document.getElementsByClassName('input-container')[0]
  clonedDiv = fragment.cloneNode(fragment);
  document.getElementById('grandparent').appendChild(clonedDiv);
}

function deleteInputs(event) {
  var target = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.remove()
}
```

```html
<div id="grandparent">
  <div class="input-container">
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" placeholder="input 1">
      <input type="number" id="input2" name="input2" placeholder="input 2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn add" onclick="addInputs(event)">Add Input</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn del" onclick="deleteInputs(event)">Delete Input</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```